# How to cook and store fresh okara for safe consumption?

Tags: food-safety, storage, japanese-cuisine, soy, soybeans

I just made soy milk for the first time in my slow juicer and want to utilize the leftover okara. I've heard that without cooking it and breaking down the enzymes, okara can be toxic to consume. I juiced the soybeans before boiling the milk, so the okara hasn't been exposed to heat yet. Apparently you're supposed to cook it down for 25 minutes or so.

I want to cook the batch and store it in the freezer so I can easily add it to meals later. What is the best method for cooking down okara that you're not ready to eat yet? Steam? Boil into a mesh? I live in a student flat and unfortunately do not have a stove, only a stovetop burner, so I cannot dehydrate it.

Much thanks!

Comment: related https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13714/can-i-use-fresh-okara-without-cooking-it

Comment: Just freeze raw is an option.

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard that uncooked okara is toxic to consume, so I don't know about that part, but you could try dry roasting it in a pan until it is dry and golden brown, that would cook it and also dry it out for storing. I have made muffins and brownies with okara with success (more or less), and I've also added it to scrambled eggs for a bit of protein boost.

Comment: Thanks for that idea! Did you add dried or fresh okara to your scrambled eggs? I won't worry about pre-cooking if it's fine to eat after just a bit of cooking, like stir frying for 5 minutes.

Comment: I used dried okara in my scrambled eggs, because it's what i happened to have. Honestly, the texture was a little weird, but i didn't use too much okara and i was willing to put up with the weird texture for the extra nutrition (and to use up a bit of my okara, haha -- I make soy milk weekly, and I tend to end up with a LOT of okara. I've taken to putting it in my compost pile because I can't use it up fast enough.)